# Memory Error when trying to load an R object file into a python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, memory, rpy2

I have an R object (.rda) file that I would like to load into a numpy array in python. Unfortunately, the following code produces a `MemoryError` that I can't seem to get to the bottom of.

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r['load']('myrobject.rda')
rils = np.array(robjects.r['myobjectname'])
```

The error is thrown with respect to the very bottom line of code, so the issue is converting the object into a numpy array, not loading the object. The data is primarily one to three digit floats ranging between 0 and 1, but there are  some characters in there as well.

My machine runs a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 16.04 and is running python 3.5.2 64 bit, so running 32 bit anything is not the problem here as it has been with related posts that I've seen. I've got 16 GB of RAM. When I use `htop` to look at memory usage during execution of this code, it gradually increases to about 4.5 GB before quitting and throwing the error.

The object I'm trying to load is 113.7MB in size, though my understanding is that .rda files are compressed.

I've never seen an error like this before, and I'd appreciate any help figuring out what is causing it and what I should do to fix it.

EDIT

Since I was asked, here is the exact error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rils_ga.py", line 10, in <module>
    rils = np.array(robjects.r['Aprobma'])
MemoryError
```

`Aprobma` corresponds to `myobjectname` that I used in the original post.

Comment: @Benjamin No. As far as I can tell the rpy2 load works similar to how load() works in R. It just puts the loaded object into the environment without you assigning a variable to it. Running the command you suggested prints the matrix.

Comment: @Benjamin it returns `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame'>`

Comment: What is the exact error thrown?

Comment: @Benjamin I've edited the post to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

If the error only occurs at the line

```
rils = np.array(robjects.r['Aprobma'])
```

this seems to indicate that the object was successfully loaded from the `.rda` file. Here you will make at least a copy of the data in the R objects in order to create a numpy array (plus eventual temp object while performing the conversion). Did you try using `asarray` to avoid duplication (see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/numpy.html#from-rpy2-to-numpy) ?